# check double value with decimal or not, if yes then add two digits, otherwise nothing

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJs. I am getting scope value from my java action as list. The price is double in database object. I need to chcek if the value is coming with decimal ex: 32.5 or not, if its 32.5 then , i need to show 32.50, if the value comes like 30.0, then it will display 30 only.

Can anyone please suggest. thanks

Comment: Please add details about "my java action as list"... A bit of code wouldn't hurt, either... :-)

Comment: AngularJS is just javascript at its core. You can use any javascript functions you want. I'm not sure I understand your rounding requirements but take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript

Comment: At first I thought like drew_w, but I think the question is not about manipulating the number if it is an integer or not, but just to present it. In that case it is an angular question and I would use a filter to present it as a string. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: yes, this is an angular question, i need to resolve it in angular way, can you pls tell me how can i filter it?

Comment: Try to write a filter that receives a number and outputs it as a nice string like you describe. Then in your template, use the variable that has the number and pass it to the filter. If you have any trouble, post a plunkr of what you have so far and we'll continue from there.

Comment: i have added some code, pls suggest the right way. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the number filter.

[Number Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)